# How do i setup a ssl encrypted reverse proxy in front of my EC2 clusters?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have 2 clusters running 2 services and several nodejs instances.

I want to have a reverse proxy in front of my clusters and i have been facing many problems/questions:

- do i have to manually update the SSL certificate on every instance everytime it expires?
- should the SSL encryption be used only outside the reverse proxy?
- do i have to deploy an nginx cluster or is there an AWS service for this?
- where can i find documentation for this?

If the answer is too big a reference to some documentation would suffice.

Comment: elastic load balancer is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options available

- AWS CloudFront
- AWS Application ELB

Using either one you can terminate tge SSL externally to the EC2 and also use AWS issued free SSL certificates.